# Palatalisation in French from Latin

Tags: prononciation, histoire, latin

How does the Latin “*SAPIAT*” become “*sache*” [saʃ] in modern French?

I thought the reason may be palatalisation as [ʃ] seems to be a palatal sound, but I can't think of any other examples to prove this theory.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR**: indeed, it is a kind of palatalisation, other examples include *cavea* > *cage*, *rabia* > *rage*, *jam* > *déjà*…

As usual in this case, I recommend the excellent *Petit précis de phonétique historique* by Noëlle Laborderie. In this case, *sapiam*'s evolution is studied in chap. 16 3.2. I will make a short summary adapted to the case of *sapiam*. I will use IPA so, latinists, feel free to add  your filthy transcriptions in [Bourciez' alphabet](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet_de_Bourciez) if you feel such urge.

### Palatalisation

#### Definition

Here¹, *[palatalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalisation)*, means “a shift of the place of articulation toward the hard palate” which can result in a sound shift, for example the palatalisation of the [k] sound in Latin *cabalus* yields a [kʲ], then a [tʲ] and eventually a [tʃ] which lead to the  [ʃ] in French *cheval*.

#### Causes

There are two main triggers of palatalisation in the study of the evolution of Latin into French, which are: reinforcement of an already palatal sound and assimilation with a contiguous palatal sound (usually the [palatal approximant [j]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatal_approximant) or a [front vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_vowel)).

In Laborderie's terminology, inherited from [Georges Straka](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georges_Straka), a palatalisation is said to be *true* if it is due to both of these phenomenon and *fake* if not.

### The appearance of [j] in intervocalic positions

The accent of Classical Latin has affected most of the subsequent phonetic evolutions of Latin, without further details, let us admit that the accent in Classical Latin *sapiam* ['sapiam] was on ['sa], that the [i] was a so-called *breve vowel* and that all breve [i] and [e] evolved in [j] around the first century BCE, so with the unrelated loss of the final [m] it became [sapja]

### The (fake) palatalisation of [j]

The palatalisation of [j] is a *fake* one according to what we saw: since [j] is already palatal, what happened was only a reinforcement.

This kind of palatalisations happened around the III century CE and its result is in general an [affricate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affricate_consonant), generally [d͡ʒ ]. But in this case, the [j] is right after a bilabial consonant, [p], which altered the palatalisation, due to the non-existent role of the tongue in its articulation. So instead of [d͡ʒ ], it yielded [ʈʲ], which then yielded [tʲʃ], [tʃ] (around the VII century CE) and finally [ʃ] around the XIII century CE.

You asked if there was other examples of this phenomenon. If found no other example of this precise occurrence [pj] > [tʃ]², but there are several other examples of fake palatalisations of [j], both in initial position, where the [j] was already present in Classical Latin such as *iam* > *déjà* or *diurnu* > *jour* and in intervocalic position, where it comes from a mutation of a [i] or [e] in hiatus, such as *rabia* > *rage* or *cavea* > *cage*.

---

¹ as everywhere else as far as I know.
² but then, I am by no mean a latinist